# Tracking user idle time within the app in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, aidl

As far as I know, there is no system API for me to get **user idle time**. When I say user idle time, I mean user have some interaction on the touch screen within my app. Therefore, I want to track it by my self. The way come up to my mind is to extends `Activity` and override `onuserinteraction` method to save the last user active time.

But the challenge is that my app have **multiple processes.** I am not sure the following way is the correct and efficient way.

I want to use `SharedPreference` with `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` flag to store the user last active time. To avoid the performance issue, I also cache the last active time within the activity in each activity. And I only save the new time to `SharedPrefernces` if the diff time > 1 second.

Is this way efficient compared to using aidl? Actually, is aidl also share variable using file? If yes, I think the two ways should have similar performance, right? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried countdowntimer??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead writing it down every time, from everywhere, make this a global function in your App:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static SharedPreferences sPreference;

    private static final long MIN_SAVE_TIME = 1000;
    private static final String PREF_KEY_LAST_ACTIVE = "last_active";
    private static final String PREF_ID_TIME_TRACK = "time_track";

    public static void saveTimeStamp(){
        if(getElapsedTime() > MIN_SAVE_TIME){
            sPreference.edit().putLong(PREF_KEY_LAST_ACTIVE, timeNow()).commit();
        }
    }

    public static long getElapsedTime(){
        return timeNow() - sPreference.getLong(PREF_KEY_LAST_ACTIVE,0);
    }

    private static long timeNow(){
        return Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sPreference = getSharedPreferences(PREF_ID_TIME_TRACK,MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

Add Application class to manifest: `<application android:name="com.example.MyApp"`

Place saving functionality in an abstract Activity class:

```
public abstract class TimedActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        MyApp.saveTimeStamp();
    }

    public long getElapsed(){
        return MyApp.getElapsedTime();
    }

}
```

Now, extend all your activities from this class, all of them will be auto-save time, and will be able to use `getElapsed()`.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, but could you give some opinion about performance more?

Comment: btw, I think is there any reason to put these functions in Application instead of in Activity base class? You want them to share the sharedPreference?

Comment: @Bear In all possibility, that `SharedPerference` is a file in your apps's data directory, and is being read/written multiple times, much like a log file. Since the content is nothing but a 64 bit number, its as fast as anything. Application class is global, and its's methods are static and you can call them from _anywhere_ in your app, not just from Activities.